# Prevent data binding from creating Id views in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kotlin-android-extensions

As mentioned in docs of [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#generated_binding):

> A public final field will be generated for each View with an ID in the layout. The binding does a single pass on the View hierarchy, extracting the Views with IDs. This mechanism can be faster than calling findViewById for several Views.

I wanted to know if there is a way to disable this functionality since I already am using Kotlin's [View Binding extension](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#view-binding) which should perform a bit better since it is on-demand view binding implementation.

Due to MVVM implementation in my current project, I need the data binding library to bind data in view xml, just need to remove its view binding implementation since it binds all the views with IDs inside the constructor of auto-generated binding class and having 2 different findViewById implementation will cost some unnecessary processing.

Comment: databinding does not use `findViewById ` - instead it traverses a view tree once and maps all the views

Comment: Right so you are saying in worst case scenario, data binding will have an upper hand compared to kotlin's extension. But consider it using with ConstraintLayout where traversing should not be that big of an issue since the layout is flat. Also, to be honest, I prefer kotlin extension because it has a much cleaner syntax for e.g. "textView.setText()" than data binding's syntax for e.g. "binding.textView.setText()". Is there a way to disable databinding's viewbinding or do I have to remove android extension?

Comment: Are you saying that it doesn't matter even if you keep both the implementation?

Comment: If databinding doesn't have the references to the views, how is going to bind the data?